# How to use Json in C# MVC to create a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, json

Now I have this class

```
public class FooResult
{
    public int sEcho;
    public Foo[] aaData;
    internal FooResult()
    {
        sEcho = 1;
        aaData = new FooRepository().GetAll().ToArray();
    }
}
```

`new FooRepository().GetAll().ToArray();` returns an array of `Foo`s.

When I use `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json` to convert this `FooResult` into a `JsonResult`, I got the string in Json Format like this:

```
{"sEcho":3, "aaData":[{"Name":"BarName"},{"Name":"FooName"}]}
```

However, I want the `aaData` to be a two dimensional array instead of an array of objects, which means it should be in this format:

```
{"sEcho":3, "aaData":[["BarName"],["FooName"]]}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What you want is invalid JSON. Not sure what you are expecting

Comment: Sorry, I missed some commas. [Here](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) is the data format I want

Comment: The commas were an obvious mistake. The invalidity is within the array itself. You can't have `["key":"value"]`. You can have `["key","value"] is you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this case you can use something like this

```
internal FooResult()
{
    sEcho = 1;
    aaData = new FooRepository().GetAll()
                                .Select(foo=>new object[]{
                                    foo.Name
                                    /*other fields what need*/
                                 })
                                .ToArray();
}
```

OR you can change settings for plugin `DataTables` and send array of objects

**NOTE**
Change type `aaData` from `Foo[]` to `object[][]`